# NGINX modules in Lua and C

Tags: c, nginx, lua

Is it possible to build and deploy modules in C or Lua for NGINX with the free version of NGINX?  Or must you have a license for NGINX PRO?

Comment: To write a module that will work with a public API, you need no permission whatsoever (copyright laws and licenses will prevent you for stealing code, though)... to use NGINX (compile with your module), you're subject to their licensing. Third party modules are written and installed all the time (search on google). I found nothing in the NGINX license that would prevent them from being used without the PRO license... however, this is not validated legal advice, just a thought and an intuition. Who would risk offering a legal answer? I have no idea. Maybe the NGINX staff.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible. Moreover, Lua module is not a part of original nginx but it's still built and distributed in all major linux distros.

http://nginx.org/LICENSE

> Redistribution and **use** in source and binary forms, **with** or without
>    **modification, are permitted** provided that the following conditions
>    are met:...

Answer (score 0):

It's of course possible and here is the famous example - https://openresty.org

OpenResty bundle is based on free open source nginx version and includes a lot of C and Lua modules.